# How to SP2013 list put it into DataTable dynamically?

Tags: javascript, development, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a sharepoint 2013 list with some items, I need to put it into DataTable dynamically, is possible create the html table automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in this way I get the columns of the list and later, I store the columns in a variable and put it in the "select" of the next ajax, that way I dynamically create the datatable view

```
   var columnaMostrar = [];
   var objColumn;
   var columna;
   var colSel;
   function CargarListadoDeAcciones() {

    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;       
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MetadataObjetos')/Fields?$filter= TypeAsString ne 'BusinessData' and EntityPropertyName ne 'BdcIdentity'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#cols").append("<th>" + "Ver Más" + "</th>");
            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                columna = item.Title
                if (columna.includes("bdil")) {

                } else {
                    objColumn = data.d.results;

                    $("#cols").append("<th>" + columna + "</th>");


                    columnaMostrar.push(columna.replace("ñ", "_x00f1_"))


                }

                colSel = columnaMostrar.toString();

            });

            console.log("Columnas",columnaMostrar);

            cargarDT();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });

}



function cargarDT() {
    var myList = [];
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var listStr = [];
    var table = $('#excelDataTable').DataTable();
    var itemID;


    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MetadataObjetos')/items?$select=BdcIdentity," + colSel,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",

        },
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                var ite = data.d.results;

                console.log(ite);
              itemID= '<a href="' + siteUrl + '/SitePages/MetadatoAtributos.aspx?Id_Objeto='+item.Id_Objeto+'">Ver</a>';
                myList = [];
                myList.push(
                        itemID
                       );
                $.each(objColumn, function (indx, itm) {
                    var colum = itm.Title;

                        var col = itm.Title;
                        var it = item[col.replace("ñ", "_x00f1_")];

                        myList.push(
                         it
                        );


                    console.log(it);

                });
                table.rows.add([

               myList


                ]).draw(false)
                $("#excelDataTable_wrapper").resize();
            });





          console.log("item", myList);


        },

        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use REST API to get list items, then using jQuery datatable to show the items. The example code below for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>     
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">      
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
    loadItems();
});
function loadItems() {    
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;    
    var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Position,Office,Age,Joining_x0020_date";    
    $.ajax({    
        url: oDataUrl,    
        type: "GET",    
        dataType: "json",    
        headers: {    
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"    
        },    
        success: mySuccHandler,    
        error: myErrHandler    
    });    
}    

function mySuccHandler(data) {    
    try {             
        $('#table_id').DataTable({             
            "aaData": data.d.results,    
            "aoColumns": [  
            {    
                "mData": "Title"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Position"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Office"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Age"    
            },  
            {    
                "mData": "Joining_x0020_date"    
            }             
            ]    
        });    
    } catch (e) {    
        alert(e.message);    
    }    
}    

function myErrHandler(data, errMessage) {    
    alert("Error: " + errMessage);    
}   
</script>
<div>    
<table id="table_id" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">    
    <thead>    
        <tr>    
            <th>Name</th>    
            <th>Position</th>    
            <th>Office</th>    
            <th>Age</th>    
            <th>Joining Date</th>            
        </tr>    
    </thead>    
    <tfoot>  
        <tr>    
            <th>Name</th>    
            <th>Position</th>    
            <th>Office</th>    
            <th>Age</th>    
            <th>Joining Date</th>                   
        </tr>   
    </tfoot>    
</table>    
</div>
```

Reference: [Using jQuery DataTable To Display SharePoint 2013 List Data On SharePoint Site Pages](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatable-to-display-sharepoint-list-data-on-share/)

Comment: thanks, but I need create dynamically the Datatable columns, that means, the json and html table must self-generate based on the columns of a sharepoint list.

Comment: You can get all the field names using REST API: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/fields, then loop the fields to build the data dynamically.